# why it shows statuscode 415 error in axios get method?

Tags: json, reactjs, axios

While fetching API data using axios get method, it returns an error showing

```
statuscode 415(Unsupported Media Type)
```

I'm getting the expected result in postman.

This request needs raw data (username) in order to fetch specified data.

```
   axios
    .get(URL,{
        username:"Name",
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;'
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

Change to

```
 axios.post(URL,{data:{ username:"Name"}, headers:{ 
'Content-Type': 'application/json;' } })
```

Comment: Error still exists.

Comment: Actually i'm passing a raw data(username:"") inside body of the request in postman.

Comment: Can you post generated code by postman, but updated the answer, not sure.

Comment: {"username" : "Binu"} This is my raw data(json)

Comment: {
    "message": "Data Listed Succesfully",
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 11,
            "from_Date": null,
            "to_Date": null,
            "filter_Type": 0,
            "assigned_By": "4",
            "assigned_To": null,

Comment: I try to help you... Please post the postman generated code or connect me remotely with anydesk or teamviewer

Answer (score 1):

You can try change headers

```
headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error 415 is given by the server when the payload you are passing is rejected and most probably because of wrong values or the format of data you have given.

`// GET request`

`axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: 'URL',
  responseType: 'application/json',
  data:{ //your data }
})`

Comment: I placed this code instead of mine and it says bad request(400)

Comment: can you add screenshot of you code or comment it here as it is.

Comment: axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: 'URL',
            responseType: 'application/json',
            data:{ username:"Binu" }
          })

Comment: Please check for this url once : 
`axios({ method: 'get',url:'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1', responseType: 'application/json', data:{ username:"Binu" } })`


are you providing you URL in url field.