# get 415 (Unsupported Media Type) when get request by axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

```
  axios.get(url, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
  })
    .then(response => {
      console.log('response',response);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('error ' + error);
    });
```

I tried to set the header " 'Content-Type': 'application/json'"

to solve this problem, it works fine on my postman, but I get 415 on my browser and axios

request in React.

Is it possible to solve this issue on my frontend?

Comment: Share postman CURL call? What you do in PostMan should be easily replicable in React. Are you sure you dont have auth or need to pass some params to get data back?

Comment: it's same, Content-Type in headers and also key and value on my Params

Comment: anything wrong with my headers format?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16693884/4830080 
It means that the Content-Type HTTP header should be set only for PUT and POST requests.

Seems like you should only specify Content-Type if type === post OR put... Try without the content-type?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58375880/why-it-shows-statuscode-415-error-in-axios-get-method

Comment: axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: 'URL',
  responseType: 'application/json',
  data:{ //your data }
})